# Itext protect pdf against modification

Tags: java, pdf, itext

i'm trying to secure my pdf. I have used this code :

```
stamper.setEncryption(USER.getBytes(), OWNER.getBytes(),
PdfWriter.ALLOW_FILL_IN | PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING | PdfWriter.ALLOW_ASSEMBLY, PdfWriter.STANDARD_ENCRYPTION_128);
```

My problem is i don't want to enter password to see the pdf, i just want a password if someone try to modify the pdf. I can't find my solution on forum.

Comment: If you don't want to enter a password for viewing, use an empty user password.

Comment: Thanks, that works

Comment: I make my comment an actual answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to enter a password for viewing, simply use an empty user password.

When opening an encrypted PDF, a PDF viewer is expected to first try to decrypt it using the empty password and ask for the password only if that fails.